# Raspberry Pi Camera Transparent Image Overlay

Tags: python, image, camera, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to overlay an transparent (png or gif) image over the pi camera preview?

I found some code but it makes a white background

```
import picamera

from PIL import Image
from time import sleep

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

camera.start_preview()

# Load the arbitrarily sized image
img = Image.open('lol.gif')
# Create an image padded to the required size with
# mode 'RGB'
pad = Image.new('RGB', (
    ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
    ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
    ))
# Paste the original image into the padded one
pad.paste(img, (0, 0))

# Add the overlay with the padded image as the source,
# but the original image's dimensions
o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tostring(), size=img.size)
# By default, the overlay is in layer 0, beneath the
# preview (which defaults to layer 2). Here we make
# the new overlay semi-transparent, then move it above
# the preview
o.alpha = 255
o.layer = 3

# Wait indefinitely until the user terminates the script
while True:
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `'RGB'` to `'RGBA'`

I don't have the conditions to test it, but I guess that will fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it does not bring the desired effect. The image becomes distorted and has fragments in it. when I am at home i can send a photo

Comment: You can perhaps try adding the overlay without padding. Use img instead of pad.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in `Image.paste` function. The third parameter is the mask will be used to paste image, as transparent pixels will maks the result, just pass the same image you are pasting as mask and will do the trick:

```
pad.paste(img, (0, 0), img)
```

As the documentation says:

> Note that if you paste an “RGBA” image, the alpha band is ignored. You can work around this by using the same image as both source image and mask.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, you will need to save the image/picture as RGB then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **both** of the first two suggestions and it works.

Change the "RGB" to "RGBA" in the **Image.new('RGBA',...** call

And add the second "img" to the **pad.paste(img, (0,0), img)** call in line.

Do both of these and it works like a charm.